# How to run our python scripts utilizing our device's GPU?

Tags: python, computer-vision, gpu, opencv, yolov8

My laptop has NVIDIA GeForce GTX1650 GPU. I want to utilize this GPU to run my Python script. Any help in the form of code would be really helpful. I mean tried researching this so much but I couldn't find.

Basically I am looping over all the frames of a video and at each frame I am using yolov8s-pose model to detect the keypoints. So since it is running on my CPU, it is very slow. So, that is the reason I need to know how to utilize my device's GPU to run it. Any help would be highly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Depends on your software framework (TensorFlow, PyTorch etc.) there are different steps to setup. Take TensorFlow as example, please read [this official doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu) as a start.

Answer (score 1):

While I am not familiar with the full extent, it seems that [Modular's Mojo](https://docs.modular.com/mojo/why-mojo.html#mlir) uses the GPU to greatly boost performance. You can use native python code, or use their syntax to enhance the code you're writing.

I am just getting started in the ML field, so I am still working to learn and understand the tools available. Mojo is just one that I've been keeping an eye on lately.

Hope this helps!